# Master relation in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to do a relationship between an Interactive Report and an Interactive Grid. I tried using the relation of interactive reports as a default, but it does not return any results on the grid.
Does anyone know of any way to make this relationship between an interactive report and an interactive grid? because I'm looking on the internet and nobody talks about how do this type of relationship.

Comment: What kind of a relation? Did you try to create a **master-detail** layout? Would that help?

Comment: Yes I did, but I'm trying to do the report for a grid, and on the internet I didn't find anything about it. Master-Detail about report have manys, but don't  about report and grid together.